# Is it permissible to open a box of matzos on Shabbos or Yom Tov if necessary for the first night of Pesach?

Tags: shabbat, passover, yom-tov, matzah

My Yehuda Matzos box here says “Box should be opened before Shabbos and Yom Tov.”

What if it is the first night of Pesach, and also Shabbos or Yom Tov, and an unopened box is the only one you have?  Can you open it, what is the Halacha?

Comment: Thank you but no, I accept that opening the box would be melakhah, but my question is, if one must open the box to have matzo to eat on first night of Pesach, what then is the Halacha?

Comment: Please [edit] that clarification into the question.

Comment: See Mishna Rosh Hashanah 4:8 that we don't violate even rabbinic prohibitions to attain on Yom tov objects required to perform biblical commandments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why the mitzvah of eating matzah would be docheh (override) melachah. Instead, the solution would be to rip/cut the box open in a way which renders it unusable (without ripping through letters/words, of course). Contact your LOR about what way of opening it would render it useless.

Comment: What if there was no non-melacha solution for a given box?

Comment: @DoubleAA I would think you may be able to have a goy do it for you, as the issur of amiras laakum is only midirabanan, and I believe there is a gemara that an issur derabanan is doiche for a mitzvas dioiraisa.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's a good point, I didn't think of that.